How to extend next/core-web-vitals on eslint.config.js?
In my nextJs project my eslint can't load my .eslintrc.json, reasearching the eslint output terminal, I found eslint is loking for a eslint.config.js file, I want to move the .eslintrc.json config to eslint.config.js
this is the eslintrc.json:
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals"
}


In general, the steps for doing this are provided here: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/migration-guide#predefined-and-shareable-configs ... Specifically for next/core-web-vitals, there is a discussion on GitHub: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/63999

Thak you, that is what I was looking for

Did you manage to get it work? I believe that it won't work because the instructions in the eslint documentation are for an npm package which is in eslintrc format. However, next/core-web-vitals is not an npm package.

I created a GitHub issue for this: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/64114
